# Is it possible to declare a variable as a string?

Tags: c++

So basically what I'm trying to find out, take this scenario:

```
std::string input;
Ask user for a string?: Apples
cin >> input;
std::string Apples = "input";
```

So basically, I ask the user for a string, and then create a variable with name of that string. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

The closest functionality is to use a map.

```
std::map<std::string, int> aMap;
```