# Return specific variable based on name of variable in C++?

Tags: c++

Is it possible, given a parameter in the input of a function, to return the variable with that specific name?

For instance, if you had the following code:

```
string returnsParameter(string parameter)
{
    string a = "test";
    string b = "test 2";
    string c = "test 3";

    return parameter;
}
```

And you ran `returnsParameter("a")`, is there some sort of way to return "test"? I tried using pointers and reference variables, but you can't make a non-constant reference.

Is there a way to do this without using maps?

Comment: `if (parameter == "a") return a;` repeated three times? C++ compilers typically do not store information about variable names in runtime, so if you want to avoid typing `if`s yourself, you'll have to resort to some metaprogramming (presumably with macros).

Comment: No. Variable names ‘disappear’ when you compile. You could do something similar with a map.

Comment: I could use if statements, but the code in actuality contains 19 variables to return; I'm wondering if there's an easier way to do so?

I wanted to use a map, but for the purpose of this exercise (this is an intro-level C++ class) I'm not allowed to store any data in an array, vector, or special object.

Comment: Then only cascade `if` would work, preprocessor macro could work as well, but that definitely not for beginners

Comment: Similar posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696345/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variable-as-a-string and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031478/get-variable-with-string-without-if-else-in-c.

Comment: "Is there a way to do this without using maps?" Anything you do will be equivalent to using a map. There are tens of thousands of ways to implement that functionality for your given case. They're all more work than just using `std::map`.

Comment: Let me guess; what you need is the functionality of map without using a map? As shown in answers you can use switch or if condition. Or you can use template based solution (where you can call function like foo<'a'>();). Tell me your data set is changing at the run time (variable) or is it a constant?

Comment: It changes at run time... I'd like to use a map, but I'm not allowed to, so I guess `if`s are what I need to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `std::map` for this purpose.
Create a `map<string, string> strings`
And add a `("a", "test")` pair in it and return `strings[parameter]`.
As far as I know, it is impossible to access the variable name. (This is my belief, I am not completely sure)

Answer (score 1):

if you are not allowed to use `std::map` then I am afraid you have to use set of conditions, note you do not need to create variables at all:

```
string returnsParameter(string parameter)
{
    if( parameter == "a" ) return "test";
    if( parameter == "b" ) return "test 2";
    if( parameter == "c" ) return "test 3";

    return "???";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your key domain exists only in alphabet a~z and data is fixed in code, you may
create a static array to index it by `char`.

```
const std::string& lookup(char key)
{
    static const std::string bank[] = {
        "Apple",
        "Banana",
        "Cranberry",        
    };
    static const size_t n = sizeof bank / sizeof bank[0];

    int i = key - 'a';
    return i >= 0 && i < n ? bank[i]: "N/A";    
}

lookup('a'); // string("Apple")
lookup('c'); // string("Cranberry")
```

Answer (score 0):

Any solution would require a map to be used, at least internally, as the system would have to use that to decide which key/value pair to return, even with variable names.

Your choices are to use std::map, hard-wire the values in with if statements, or have your own lookup table. Remember however, that you need to have a default return value just in case the key is not found.

```
string returnsParameter(string parameter)
{
    vector<string> values =
    {
        "a", "test",
        "b", "test 2",
        "c", "test 3"
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i += 2 )
    {=
        if(values[i] == parameter) return values[i + 1];
    }

    return "Not Found";
}
```